# How to uninstall individual apps from MS Office 2021?

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-app

I just want to install Word, Excel and PowerPoint from Office 2021 however, there is no option to opt-out from other apps getting installed alongside. Is there any way to uninstall those useless apps easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time to get an answer to this question.
I found an answer, and I'm providing a link to it here (to preserve their copyrights):

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/custom-install-uninstall-office-apps/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).